# How to configure apache to allow rewrite rules for directories?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have some configuration in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

All urls redirects to /index.php

But if folder exists, it goes to folder, not to /index.php

why?

I tried this solution to make this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

But this like a previously example goes to directory =(

Comment: All requests must go to index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
#turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

#specify your base
RewriteBase /

#make sure, your index.php won't be rewritten
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]

#rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?para=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But if folder exists, it goes to folder, not to /index.php

Try disabling `MultiViews` – it is often interfering in such cases.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews